# Reading in JSON files in R with unicode strings

Tags: r, jsonlite

I have a txt file, that contains a list of json objects, with 1 of the keys containing an emoji representation in JavaCode format.

I want to parse the json file and convert it to CSV, with the column called emoji, and the emoji to be kept in its JavaCode representation for eg. `"\uD83D\uDEB6\u200D\u2642\uFE0F"`.

Is there any way to do that? Currently, I'm using jsonlite to read it in but it seems to auto-convert the emoji data to be like this (which I assume is its Unicode representation): `"<U+0001F6B6><U+200D><U+2640><U+FE0F>"`

This is the code to read it in:

```
df <- fromJSON(data_file)
head(df)
```

Edited the question to include a sample json object from the list:

```
 {
  "x": [
    {
     "y": "a",
     "emoji": "\uD83D\uDEB6\u200D\u2642\uFE0F"
    }
   ],
   "z": "b"
 }
```

Comment: Can you please give a valid example that doesn't use "..." so we can actually try to read it in R? What emoji are you expecting there? How exactly are you checking the value? What is the code you used to read the JSON? Are you `cat()`ing the value to the console? What OS are you using? It's possible the system font might not recognize that particular emoji.

Comment: This might be an OS specific question. Are you using Windows?

Comment: @MrFlick edited the question to include the code and the exact value. I'm using Windows

Comment: @danlooo Yup I'm using Windows. Currently the formatting of the emoji seems to be in JavaCode, and I want to keep it as a string instead of R auto processing it to display in some rendition of Unicode. When I send it to CSV, it also keeps the Unicode string, which I don't want